# Wordpress Site Is Blank - Only Links Showing For Homepage

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Just an FYI, I'm an amateur blogger who doesn't know much about coding.

I've been facing a problem recently and I don't know what to do.

My website homepage shows up blank, with just links (http://shlokamariwala.com/)

I've tried to check for any errors in my backend but all seems to be working fine!

I've also uninstalled all plugins to check, but that didn't make a difference.

Please let me know how to go about this! I'm happy to provide any specific additional information needed. Also, since I'm not very well versed in coding, I apologise for my use of lay-man terms in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I get to your website, most content is not coming from your domain, but is loaded from https://secureservercdn.net/50.62.198.97/qxw.3db.myftpupload.com/.

Also your own site is not using SSL (https), but insecure http.

Many browsers and most anti spamer browser plugins like privacy badger or uBlock Origin will refuse to load this.

Another point may be that you are using canvas data, but also this is blocked by default in modern browsers.

Maybe take a look in the wordpress server site settings and check your servername.